# Rsync delete only remove older source files

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, android, rsync

Ok, I could probably spend a lot of time writing a complex set of bash scripts that would accomplish this, but I'm hoping this functionality already exists somewhere.

I have a device in my car which functions as a dashcam. I records video in 3-minute segments. When I get home, it automatically connects to the wifi, and starts an ssh daemon.

I want something which I can call from cron, to ssh in, and rsync the videos to my linux machine. So far this is easy. What I want to do then, is delete files from the dashcam device, but not ALL of them - I want to delete ONLY ones that are older than X days. And I want this somehow tied in with the rsync so it absolutely only deletes them if rsync knows it has copied them.

If rsync had an option like "-remove-source-files-older-than" it would work perfectly.

EDIT: Perhaps there is some tool other than rsync that would be better suited for this task?

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2-step approach, that will work:

First, transfer ALL the files as usual with rsync.
Then, start another rsync-step with the `--remove-source-files` option but **execute it only on the old video files**.

ways to do this (feeding it only the old files):

- Use ZSH instead of bash, see the answer here: [rsync N newest files in a directory](https://superuser.com/questions/208591/rsync-n-newest-files-in-a-directory?rq=1). For example, selecting all the files that are older than 24h: `ls *(mh+24)`
- use some piping of `ls`,`grep`, etc. to filter the files and feed them to rsync, see the other answer in the link

Comment: Note that the remote system is Android, so I don't have as much flexibility there with what shells to use, etc. I am running rsync on the linux machine side, copying files from the Android device (which runs SSHDroid)

Comment: And I'd really like it to be tied in with rsync more directly, so that it only deletes files that it has verified it has copied.

Comment: The tie-in with rsync is already there in my solution. I don't know about Andriod, but you might still be able to hack a solution with `ls` et. al